# How to bind data template of a listbox to class fields

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate

I have a Class Person that consists of FirstName and LastName. I created an object of type ObservableCollection and filled it with some data, bounded it to Listbox.ItemsSource via code-behind. Now I want that data to be displayed on the Window inside a listbox, but via data template, so I can choose which fields of a class to appear..

So, one item would represent FirstName and Lastname in two separate textblocks.

```
<Window x:Class="PlayList.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:PlayList"
Title="Media Player PlayList" 
Height="300" 
Width="300" >

<Grid Height="224" Name="grid1" Width="261" >
    <ListBox Height="100" x:Name="listBox1" Margin="12,0,12,124"  MouseDoubleClick="listBox1_MouseDoubleClick" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Surname}"/>

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

Edit:

```
personae = new ObservableCollection<Person> { per1, per2, per3, per5, per4 };         listBox1.ItemsSource = personae;
```

Comment: Do not forget to set the data context for the main window to the code behind  instance or to some view model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure FirstName and LastName are properties, not fields.
Setting the Items Source properly and your example template should be enough

Answer (score 3):

If the ListBoxItem's data context object contains properties `string FirstName` and `string Surname`, having the following in the markup would suffice:

```
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Output window shows the binding problems that appear at runtime. Most likely your ListBox Items are not bound to an observable collection of items. Are you populating your list box items collection in code behind or using view model?

Comment: I didn't note the difference between a property and a field :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind to [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), only to [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) (which preferably are in a class [implementing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) if you need changes to reflect in the view).